# How to activate the loop only if mouse click is being held down? (Stop the loop when releasing the key) PYTHON 3

Tags: python, winapi, button, click, mouse

I have a rather simple script here:

```
 import win32api

def press():
        lmb_status = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        return lmb_status < 0

while True:
        if lmb_status():
                print ("print this")
                win32api.Sleep(1000)
                print ("do not print this")
```

The problem is if I click the left mouse button, the script gets executed as a whole, but my main goal is the script should stop as soon as the key is released. So if I make a click (and if it is released under a second) it should only activate the first command "print this", but it should not print the second one. But it does so it is not working as I want it to be working.

How could I make it work?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT 1:

After reading the two helpful comments, I think that I am in the right direction, but it is still not working as it should: When I release the click, the "Interruption." only gets executed if both of the print commands have been done.

```
import win32api

def click():
        left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        return left < 0
def noclick():
        left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        return left >= 0

while True:
                function = False
                win32api.Sleep(10)
                if click():
                        function = True
                elif noclick():
                        function = False
                if function == False:
                         print("Interruption.")
                if function == True:
                        print ("This should be printed.")
                        win32api.Sleep(1000)
                        print ("This should not.")
```

Comment: one way to do it is have a thread querying mouse events that will trigger a `flag` when released, you can then use short circuits in your loop like this : `flag and print ("print this")` so the moment `flag` becomes false your lines wont trigger anymore. this is a quick hack and is probably not the best way of doing thing

Comment: Python promotes an imperative programming model, but Windows uses an event driven model. Given enough time writing Python code deprives your mind of thinking in anything but imperatives. The solution (to the undisclosed problem) is to respond to events.

Comment: Hey guys! Thank you both for answering, I think you guys have put me in the right direction, however, my script is still not working as it should be.

Please check the edited post for the script I have tried. When I release the key the printing won't get executed ASAP, because it will wait for the first to finish.

Comment: ** Please check the edited post for the script, so you can see what I came up with. When I release the key the printing does not get executed asap, because it waits for the previous one to finish. ** Corrected grammar.

Comment: You aren't headed in the right direction. The code is still polling, with all the drawbacks inherent to sampling. You'll need to respond to events the system generates for you on user input. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program) what a simple program looks like in C++. You'll need to absorb its physiology, and translate that into Python code. If you are looking for a robust solution.

Comment: Message callback still need to wait the `Sleep()` method before get the Button Up message. You could create a thread to run the loop and terminate the thread when the left button is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pyHook` to get the mouse click event, and create a thread to run the loop when left button is pressed, and terminate the thread when the button is up.

```
import win32api, win32gui, pyHook, pythoncom, ctypes, inspect, sys, _thread

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
ThreadId = 0

def loop():
    while True:
        print ("This should be printed.")
        win32api.Sleep(1000)
        print ("This should not.")

def onMouse_leftdown(event):
    global ThreadId
    if(ThreadId == 0):
        print("start loop")
        ThreadId = _thread.start_new_thread(loop,())
        return True
    return True

def onMouse_leftup(event):
    global ThreadId
    if(ThreadId != 0):
        print("end loop")
        hThread = kernel32.OpenThread(0x0001, 0, ThreadId)
        ret = kernel32.TerminateThread(hThread,0)
        ThreadId = 0
        return True
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hm = pyHook.HookManager()
    hm.MouseLeftDown = onMouse_leftdown
    hm.MouseLeftUp = onMouse_leftup
    hm.HookMouse()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
    hm.UnhookMouse()
```